# Laptop is Suddenly Off While Suspended

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, suspend, hybrid-graphics

I'm on a dual boot machine (`Acer Aspire E1-572G`) running `Windows 7 SP1 64` bit and `Linux Mint 17.2 64 bit`.

Everything is fine, but sometimes while my laptop is in sleep mode (suspended) it turns off, as if someone pushed the power button for several seconds.

This never happens on Windows 7, which indicates that I have no hardware problems.

I use suspend very frequently, and a fix for this problem is a high priority.

***NOTE:***  My UEFI is configured for legacy boot (BIOS).

I had the same problem on this same setup, but on `Ubuntu 14.04LTS`. Apportcheck reported a suspend/resume failure.

I have Hybrid Graphics (`Intel HD Graphics 4400` & `AMD RADEON HD 8750M`) and I'm using `fglrx` which is a proprietary driver. Should I install `radeon` instead? Moreover, should I disable the discrete GPU (AMD)? After doing some search, some articles mention that having hybrid GPUs may cause suspend problems.

Comment: Just to check, but it doesn't turn off because it runs out of battery?

Comment: It happens even if the laptop is plugged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I solved this problem in this new thread.](https://askubuntu.com/a/950433/453055)