# My laptop sometimes turns off when suspending it

Tags: 16.04, suspend, power-management

I'm on latest `Ubuntu 16.04` fully up-to-date, `x64 Acer Aspire E1-572G`. Graphics drivers are the open source ones: `radeon` for the discrete card, and `i915` for the integrated card (which is used by everything unless I set `DRI_PRIME=1` which switches graphics processing to `radeon`).

I also use `tlp` for power management and here is my current `tlp` configuration: https://pastebin.com/dpCuTF1b

BIOS is in UEFI (default) mode with secure boot turned off. `systemctl --failed` reports `0 loaded units listed` which indicates all services started successfully.

**Here is the weird behavior that's going on:**

Some times when I put the computer to sleep (suspend), it just turns off. It doesn't even shutdown. It turns off as if I took off the battery from the laptop. I'm not sure if this happens only when I close the lid, but I guess it happens even if I suspend the laptop without closing the lid (by clicking the suspend button). I will feedback later if this problem ever happens without closing the lid, because I can't actually remember right now.

When this happens, the background wallpaper is no longer displayed on the lock screen on later system restarts, until I change the wallpaper again.

`/var/crash/` is empty, and `/var/log/boot.log` has a report indicating that `fsck` is fixing some orphaned inodes. Actually, here are some logs:

- /var/log/boot.log: https://pastebin.com/LTYK9FJE
- /var/log/syslog: https://pastebin.com/Q2PLLZA5
- /var/log/kern.log: https://pastebin.com/jWuTSqe6

I had all versions of Windows (7, 8, 8.1, 10) installed on this laptop before and I never had this issue. I also performed `memtest86` tests and they all succeeded.

This crash is very annoying because every time it happens I use `debsums` and `diff` to make sure nothing is corrupted.

I'm ready to share more info upon request, Thank you!

---

`sudo blkid` output:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="5331-7707" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="3f8152ad-fccf-4675-9e9d-8ad5ad225726"
/dev/sda2: UUID="715420bf-c241-4f2d-bec4-01a73dbb9806" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0f05b77f-4b96-4f0c-a5cb-eb425a230467"
/dev/sda3: UUID="ffaf844c-98b3-4b94-89c7-c0e69a456921" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="5c622918-0497-4354-b187-15f08cd35fc3"
```

`cat /etc/fstab` output:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=715420bf-c241-4f2d-bec4-01a73dbb9806 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=5331-7707  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=ffaf844c-98b3-4b94-89c7-c0e69a456921 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

`sudo fdisk -l` output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 698.7 GiB, 750156374016 bytes, 1465149168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 82BDC3DF-6864-454F-AA6D-F59B05865FEF

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2     1050624 1448617983 1447567360 690.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  1448617984 1465147391   16529408   7.9G Linux swap
```

`ls -alt /var/crash` output:

```
total 8
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Aug 21 09:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 Aug  1 14:34 ..
```

`grep -i Temperature_Celsius /var/log/syslog` output:

```
Aug 21 09:35:49 AdamPC smartd[1032]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 109 to 115
Aug 21 09:57:55 AdamPC smartd[1032]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 115 to 109
Aug 21 15:33:14 AdamPC smartd[1032]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 109 to 111
Aug 21 15:57:54 AdamPC smartd[1032]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 111 to 107
Aug 21 16:27:54 AdamPC smartd[1032]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 107 to 106
Aug 21 16:57:54 AdamPC smartd[1032]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 106 to 105
Aug 21 18:21:06 AdamPC smartd[1024]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 105 to 111
Aug 21 18:51:06 AdamPC smartd[1024]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 111 to 109
Aug 21 19:21:07 AdamPC smartd[1024]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 109 to 106
Aug 21 20:26:28 AdamPC smartd[1024]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 106 to 113
Aug 21 21:07:26 AdamPC smartd[998]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 113 to 114
```

Screenshot showing that my disk isn't burning:

[image]

Uninstalling `tlp` did not solve this problem. My computer suddenly turned off again. This is the syslog output before suspend:

```
Aug 26 14:03:45 AdamPC NetworkManager[1012]: <info>  [1503745425.2165] manager: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Aug 26 14:03:45 AdamPC NetworkManager[1012]: <info>  [1503745425.2166] manager: sleeping...
Aug 26 14:03:45 AdamPC NetworkManager[1012]: <info>  [1503745425.2166] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [30 10 37]
Aug 26 14:03:45 AdamPC NetworkManager[1012]: <info>  [1503745425.2314] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Aug 26 14:03:45 AdamPC wpa_supplicant[1172]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Aug 26 14:03:46 AdamPC systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug 26 14:03:46 AdamPC systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Aug 26 14:03:46 AdamPC systemd-sleep[6098]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
Aug 26 14:03:46 AdamPC systemd-sleep[6099]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
Aug 26 14:03:46 AdamPC systemd-sleep[6098]: Suspending system...
Aug 26 14:28:55 AdamPC rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="1036" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
```

The first line in the excerpt is when I closed the lid (triggered the suspend). The last line of the excerpt is when I powered on the laptop after the accident (See the timings). Weird thing, I get the same log when having a normal suspend. Complete syslog: http://pasted.co/7354277e

---

**Important Update**

I reinstalled `tlp` after finding that it is not the cause of the problem. Now I noticed something that might help us scope down the problem. I can replicate the accident by suspending the system and while suspending it, I  attach/detach my mouse repeatedly (or any USB device). Once I do that, the accident happens immediately. **This can only be replicated while `tlp` is installed**. I guess `tlp` makes it happen more consistently?

**The Update That Solved The Problem**

I resumed debugging today. Launched my eyeballs towards `/var/log/syslog` until I finally found something worthy:

```
Sep  5 20:19:20 AdamPC kernel: [  167.044965] pci_pm_suspend(): hcd_pci_suspend+0x0/0x30 returns -16
Sep  5 20:19:20 AdamPC kernel: [  167.044971] dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x150 returns -16
Sep  5 20:19:20 AdamPC kernel: [  167.044973] PM: Device 0000:00:14.0 failed to suspend: error -16
Sep  5 20:19:20 AdamPC kernel: [  167.044975] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
```

Device 0000:00:14.0? Let's run `lspci`:

```
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
```

Made some google search and [found the solution in ArchWiki.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Instantaneous_wakeups_from_suspend) Look at my answer for the solution.

Comment: I'd uninstall tlp and see if your problem goes away.

Comment: I'll do that then. But I really can't imagine living without it. It saves tons of battery.

Comment: You can always reinstall tlp later, but for testing, we should eliminate the most obvious first. Make sure you reboot after uninstalling tlp.

Comment: I uninstalled tlp and rebooted. This issue doesn't happen very often. It will take sometime till I feedback here.

Comment: I looked at your syslog, and your machine has some problems... it's burning up... the disk temp was over 100 celcius... and you have 2 disk partitions with the same ID. Edit your question with the `terminal` output of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `sudo fdisk -l` and `ls -alt /var/crash`.

Comment: Since you've uninstalled tlp, monitor your disk temp with `grep -i Temperature_Celsius /var/log/syslog`.

Comment: And you had `thermald` and `tlp` running at the same time!

Comment: I've been using TLP for many months and never had any suspend issues. Indeed it fixes over heating problems I had.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix do you have `thermald` installed along with `tlp`?

Comment: @heynnema Yes. Trying for pure Intel solution as much as possible, Thermald, PowerClamp, Dell BIOS updates and Intel Microcode are all updated after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04 and having TONS of problems. Systemd changes for suspend/resume. Overheating and power off at 90C+ required PowerClamp. Tried Dell 8000 Fan control (i8kfan) with bad luck. Tried all kinds of PM stuff, ACPI stuff and other stuff I forget before finally finding `tlp` which brought overheating under control. Now runs about 50C with Chrome. 60C with Chrome and Firefox running at the same time (new problem w/HTML5 pause)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Wow! After all that... would you generalize and say that Dell isn't a good choice for Ubuntu? Or just your model? Maybe a custom thermald config file would have helped?

Comment: No I think it was more Ubuntu being a collage of gnome, systemd with some Unity sprinkled on top. Plus upgrade from 14.04 which had turbo-boost jailed (p-states I think or maybe c-states) because it was broken then but activated in 16.04. Plus something about sysinit or something switching to systemd.  A clean install of 16.04 might have been easier. Dell is one of the few laptops you can buy with Ubuntu pre-installed FTR so I wouldn't bash it. (no pun intended).

Comment: Related chat room for this: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64249/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-my-laptop-sometimes-turns-off-when-suspending-i

Comment: @ThomasWard as you can see from the length of the comments, a lot of information was exchanged in the troubleshooting process, and I needed a scratchpad to keep all of the important information in one place (not scattered throughout the comments). When complete, I would have turned the scratchpad into a normal answer. I just needed more time to finish the process...

Comment: @MyNameIsUser please do update #1 in my new answer. Report back how it went.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Add the following to `/etc/rc.local` before `exit 0`:

```
echo 0 > /sys/power/pm_async
echo EHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup # echo if enabled, if disabled delete this line
echo EHC2 > /proc/acpi/wakeup # echo if enabled, if disabled delete this line
echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup # echo if enabled, if disabled delete this line
```

Then reboot.
To see if EHC1, EHC2 or XHC are enabled or disabled, run `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup`
See my updated question for the rationale behind these scripts.

---

**Special Thanks**

To [heynnema](https://askubuntu.com/users/4272/heynnema), because without him I wouldn't have reached this stage of debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the special thanks. I'm glad you found a temporary workaround, but I don't think it's the real fix. I noticed the clip of syslog that you added, and it's having a problem with your wireless during suspend. Did you modify /etc/default/grub, or anything in /etc/modprobe.d with parameters that look like "nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp2s0 disabled\_11b\_rates=0"?

Comment: You are welcome. I will feedback if this problem happens ever gain. Regarding `grub.cfg` and `modprobe.d/`, I never edited them. I also did not find any thing related to the wifi card in `modprobe.d/`.

Comment: `grep -i 11b /etc/modprobe.d/*`

Comment: `grep -i 11b /etc/modprobe.d/*` returned nothing.

Comment: Do you use a DKMS driver for your wireless? `dkms status` and `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: No I use `ath9k` which is the default (I knew this by looking at your second command). `dkms status` returned `virtualbox, 5.0.40, 4.10.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 5.0.40, 4.10.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed`

Comment: If you connect wirelessly, comment out your rc.local fix, reboot, disconnect from the network, and see if suspend works properly.

Comment: @heynnema I thank you so much for trying to find the real deep cause of this problem. However, since I'm currently satisfied by the results of my workaround, and I'm a little busy with work, I'll have to pause debugging this problem for the time being. Of course, if my workaround fails me later, I'll resume debugging, and feedback the results here.

Comment: @heynnema you might be interested in my latest findings :) See my updated question too. Finally found the relevant logs! So do you think that this is the real cause behind all of this? I want to hear your opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm still not satisfied with your fix/workaround. Are you running with BIOS 2.17? If not, update it at https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/4867;-;Aspire%20E1-572G

Comment: Yes, my BIOS is 2.17. It is the latest one. (Installed it 2 years ago when I was facing the same problem)

Comment: There are kernel boot parameters that can be passed by GRUB at boot time. Like acpi=off, etc. Search for "boot parameters" here, or "linux boot parameters" via Google. You should be looking for a long list of boot parameters, and find the acpi section to start the research.

Comment: See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters and https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html

Comment: The list is quite overwhelming.

Comment: That's why I suggested only looking at the `acpi` portion. For testing, you could temporarily disable your workaround, and temporarily add `acpi=off` to the boot parameters `quiet splash` in `/etc/default/grub`, and `sudo update-grub`, reboot, and see if that makes any difference on your problem.

Comment: I'm not able to boot Ubuntu with `acpi=off` kernel parameter. The computer hangs with the Ubuntu violet color. Then I hold and press the power button to forcibly shut down the system. After that I turn on the laptop, go into GRUB's menu, edit the boot parameters, remove the `acpi=off`, and then `ctrl-x` and the system boots with ACPI logs/errors. (`ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed` from the syslog, for example)

Comment: Actually the ACPI error mentioned above is not related to adding the `acpi=off` kernel parameter, it is logged every time I boot regardless.

Comment: You might add `acpi_os_name=Linux`, and research `acpi=` and `acpi_sleep=` on the kernel boot parameters list.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

We uninstalled `tlp` and also installed `intel-microcode`.

**Update #1:**

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Problem occurred again now. Uninstalling `tlp` did not solve the problem.

Comment: Are you able to find anything in /var/log/syslog* around the time of the problem? (more /var/log/syslog*)

Comment: I updated my question. I'll add more of the syslog if you happen to need it.

Comment: @MyNameIsUser Thanks for the syslog update. You captured the immediate suspend info, but the info before and after the core suspend event will give me more information. Notice when processes are getting notified to shutdown, etc., and after suspend, any activity prior to the power up.

Comment: Here's the complete syslog: http://pasted.co/7354277e Sorry it is quite large but has everything.

Comment: @MyNameIsUser I reviewed the syslog, and the only thing that I notice is a lot of **mce** errors (machine check, hardware error). You should be able to see for your self with `grep -i "mce:" /var/log/syslog*`. Why don't you go to http://www.memtest86.org and download the free memory test and run at least one pass minimum, more passes if you have the time.

Comment: I already did that before posting this question on askubuntu. All tests passed with zero errors. It is worth noting that this suspend problem has never happened on Windows before, and maybe Arch linux too (I'm not very sure about Arch, but I don't remember the problem happening on it).

Comment: @MyNameIsUser Because of all the mce's, you might try reseating your CPU chip. Also look for a processor diagnostic program that you can run for a couple of hours. You've run the hard disk SMART tests, yes? I think that you still might have a hardware problem.

Comment: I'll look into that. But how can it be a hardware problem when it doesn't happen when on Windows?

Comment: @MyNameIsUser Windows uses the hardware differently than Linux. Although the fact that Windows runs, isn't a 100% guarantee that there's still not a hardware problem.